# Cito bicycle history / old steel bike identification

Tags: vintage, steel, belt-drive, history

I have a Cito Master Star bicycle but cannot find any info about it online. I think it is a 1969 model as it has a 69 stamped onto it. It also has aero coronado cranks but has some belt drive system I'm not familiar with. Any info on it would be appreciated. Thank you for all your replies so far.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It appears you didn't manage to include your picture; you might want to [edit] the question to add it.  Beyond that, though, the "worth" of your bike is either what it would cost you to replace it or what someone else is willing to pay for it.  There are sites (for example, without making a recommendation, there's bicycle blue book) that will estimate what your bike might resell for, but I'm pretty sure your bike is too old for their databases.  Is there a reason you *need* to have a value for it?

Comment: Be aware that valuations of bicycles and other items is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I doubt that it's as old as 1969, but probably 70s.  It's a very unique bike, with belt drive and the front hub brake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a unique-looking bike.

The seat stays appear to be bolted on top and bottom, which is how a PO was able to fit a belt without cutting the frame or using a split belt.  That it has track ends rather than a dropout suggests this might have been a track bike in its early years.

However track bikes generally don't have brakes for track use.  It is possible the same PO fitted the front hub brake (wise move) and uses the fixed gear rear hub as the back brake.

The belt drive system is a relatively recent addition, and I guess this frame was selected because of the rear stays.   I can't find a "coronado" crank with belt drive, so its possible this combo is an aftermarket replacement of traditional chainrings with a single drive belt spindle.

The rear hub appears to have a "pull chain" hanging from the side and tied by string.  This could be a way of making an IGH into a single speed ?  Seems dodgy to me, I'm not sure if an IGH would like being locked up for rear braking, or more likely this bike only has a single brake and the rear coasts.

The head tube angle looks very "reclined" compared to more modern designs.  I bet this bike is easy to ride no-handed due to the slack angles.

Obviously the handlebars are a replacement - this bike would have had drop bars or track drops originally.  The saddle is definitely much newer too.

Lastly, the tubes appear to have a Woods or Dunlop valve.  These have become less common globally, other than China and the Netherlands.  I would also suggest looking closely at the tyres for dry rot and cracking, for safety, they don't look new.

All in all, sweet bike and you'll enjoy riding it.   If it were me I'd fit a rear brake, connect the IGH to a shifter, and possibly go back to drop bars.

Comment: Wow thank you! Very insightful! The rear hub is a torpedo pentasport 5 speed hub(twin chain pull) with a backpedal braking system. The wheels are Van Schothurst stainless steel, weigh a ton but quite nice to look at, and not original. I'm thinking about changing the handlebars to drop bars as I prefer the look of them to the current ones, but it is very comfortable to ride at the moment. It seems to be a German built bike, but I have no catalogues to look at as the company Cito was bought by a brand called Kalkhoff. I'm considering buying a shifter for the hub but I'm finding they're not cheap

Comment: The frame reminds me of an old 1930s three speed (still made new in India). The frame angles, the bolt on seat stays and the pump mount on the back of the seat tube. Maybe someone took a frame like that, stripped it down, painted it and made it into a belt drive.

Comment: @DavidD good point - bolt-together is more repairable than welded/brazed construction.  The angles are very slack.

Comment: @Thomas Link to Sachs hub production date codes http://www.808.dk/?hub-production-date My bet is that the hub was modified to take a belt. Any names on the belt or sprocket?

Comment: Thanks! That is possible, I've taken apart the entire IGH and now that I think about it it was a little different where the sprocket is. There are absolutely no markings on the sprocket or front ring unfortunately. The belt is a generic one I sourced off eBay so that wouldn't help unfortunately.

Comment: The hub was built in June 1988 :)